# Appending the datetime to the end of every line in a 600 million row file

Tags: awk, sed, bigdata

I have a 680 million rows (19gig) file that I need the datetime appended onto every line. I get this file every night and I have to add the time that I processed it to the end of each line. I have tried many ways to do this including sed/awk and loading it into a SQL database with the last column being defaulted to the current timestamp.

I was wondering if there is a fast way to do this? My fastest way so far takes two hours and that is just not fast enough given the urgency of the information in this file.  It is a flat CSV file.

edit1:

Here's what I've done so far:

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" '{ print $0","date}' lrn.ae.txt > testoutput.txt
```

Time = 117 minutes

```
perl -ne 'chomp; printf "%s.pdf\n", $_' EXPORT.txt > testoutput.txt
```

Time = 135 minutes

```
mysql load data local infile '/tmp/input.txt' into table testoutput
```

Time = 211 minutes

Comment: you have said that you *have tried many ways to do this including sed/awk*. Show that ways and perhaps, you'll get some recommendations for optimization

Comment: Not only must you show the ways you have tried, you must list the specific drawbacks with each one that prevented you from using it.

Comment: `I get this file every night` - cant you ask whoever is generating it to add the timestamp while they do so? Assuming the answer is "no", [edit] your question to show us what your `fastest way so far` is so we can help you figure out what's wrong with it. Also include concise, testable sample input and expected output as not all CSVs are created equal so we'd need to know what yours looks like (can it contain commas inside fields, does it use double quotes around fields, does it escape quotes within fields by a backslash or doubling up, can fields contain newlines, etc.).

Comment: What is the rationale of adding the same time stamp to all records?

Comment: I added my times. And i'm sorry about the way I asked, i'm still new to stack overflow. I cannot get the file to be changed either sadly. The rational is somewhat weird, the way that the file is being used is dependent on when i actually got the file

Comment: You **might** be able to shave off a few seconds by using sed instead of awk (e.g. `date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" sed 's#$#'"$date"'#' lrn.ae.txtbut`) otherwise what you're doing is already the fastest way to do it so you're SOL, sorry. Obviously appending the timestamp to the file name would make much more sense.

Comment: `perl -lnse 'print $_, ",", $date' -- -date="$(date "+%F %r")" infile > outfile` might be *slightly* faster than your current perl command.

Comment: How long does it take to do `time cp big-data-file /dev/null` or `time cp big-data-file copy-of-big-data-file`?  Copying 19 GiB shouldn't be taking a couple of hours — unless perhaps the file is on an NFS-mounted file system over a slow network, or something equally ghastly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that simplifies [mjuarez' helpful approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44374006/45375):

```
yes "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" | paste -d',' file - | head -n "$(wc -l < file)" > out-file
```

Note that, as with the approach in the linked answer, *you must know the number of input lines in advance* - here I'm using `wc -l` to count them, but if the number is fixed, simply use that fixed number.

- `yes` keeps repeating its argument indefinitely, each on its own output line, until it is terminated.
- `paste -d',' file -` pastes a corresponding pair of lines from `file` and stdin (`-`) on a single output line, separated with `,`
- Since `yes` produces "endless" output, `head -n "$(wc -l < file)"` ensures that processing stops once all input lines have been processed.

The use of a pipeline acts as a memory throttle, so running out of memory shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify if the timestamps have to be *different* for each of the lines.  Would a "start of processing" time be enough?

If so, a simple solution is to use the `paste` command, with a pre-generated file of timestamps, exactly the same length as the file you're processing.  Then just `paste` the whole thing together.  Also, if the whole process is I/O bound, as others are speculating, then maybe running this on a box with an SSD drive would help speed up the process.

I just tried it locally on a 6 million row file (roughly 1% of yours), and it's actually able to do it in less than one second, on Macbook Pro, with an SSD drive.

```
 ~> date; time paste file1.txt timestamps.txt > final.txt; date
 Mon Jun  5 10:57:49 MDT 2017

 real   0m0.944s
 user   0m0.680s
 sys    0m0.222s
 Mon Jun  5 10:57:49 MDT 2017
```

I'm going to now try a ~500 million row file, and see how that fares.

Updated:

Ok, the results are in.  Paste is blazing fast compared to your solution, it took just over 90 seconds total to process the whole thing, 600M rows of simple data.

```
~> wc -l huge.txt 
600000000 huge.txt
~> wc -l hugetimestamps.txt 
600000000 hugetimestamps.txt
~> date; time paste huge.txt hugetimestamps.txt > final.txt; date
Mon Jun  5 11:09:11 MDT 2017

real    1m35.652s
user    1m8.352s
sys 0m22.643s
Mon Jun  5 11:10:47 MDT 2017
```

You still need to prepare the timestamps file ahead of time, but that's a trivial bash loop.  I created mine in less than one minute.

Comment: Wouldn't the time to create the file with 500 million rows of timestamps take a while as well? I would use awk/perl again to do this.

Comment: @michaelJC it literally took me less than one minute to create the file.

Comment: @MichaelJC this is what I used to create the 500 million rows of timestamps, run it as many times as needed:  `for number in `seq 1 100`; do cat timestamps.txt >> newtimestamps.txt; done`

Comment: while you're at it, could you please test the timings of the `join` solution posted below?  It uses one line for time stamp (but has additional processing).

Comment: @mjuarez I think i'm doing something wrong. I'm doing just a very simple for i in seq 1 600000000 do cat timestamp.txt >> newtimestamp.txt done and its taking a very long time

Comment: @MichaelJC don't do it all at once, you're becoming I/O bound at that point.  Do it in three steps.  Create a 1000 timestamp row file, then run the loop on it 1000 times.   Then run the loop on the resulting file another 1000 times, and you'll now have 1B rows in a file.  That whole process took about a minute for me.  Also, take a look at @karakfa solution below, you might not even need this pre-generated timestamps file.  The `join` solution seems to be even better.

Comment: or `head -1000000 <(yes $(date)) > timestamps`

Comment: I get very comparable results on a comparable machine (Early 2015 MacBook Pro 13" — 8 GiB RAM, 250 GiB SSD).  It takes under 2 minutes to `cat` an 8 GiB file twice to create a 16 GiB file (and provided there is enough free space, it took under 2 minutes to concatenate a 1 GiB, a 2 GiB and a 16 GiB file to create the 19 GiB file; when there wasn't enough space, it took over 7 minutes).  Editing the data on the fly should be a small increment on the time (not more than a factor of, oh, 4).  So, the 2 hour times in the question are surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to test is

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %r" > timestamp
$ join -t, -j9999 file timestamp | cut -d, -f2-
```

or time stamp can be generated in place as well `<(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")`

`join` creates a cross product of the first file and second file using the non-existing field (9999), and since second file is only one line, practically appending it to the first file.  Need the `cut` to get rid of the empty key field generated by `join`

Comment: I got essentially the same result, right around ~90 seconds, and there's no need to pre-generate a huge timestamp file, just the single one.  I like your solution better than mine.  Can you quickly explain how join works in this case? Currently waiting on the results for generating the timestamp in place, but I suspect it will be just slightly slower, if at all.

Comment: I tried this but i got memory exhausted and it was taking longer than 90 seconds, and i was doing it on a file with only 100 million rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the same (current) datetime to each row in the file, you might as well leave the file as it is, and put the datetime in the filename instead. Depending on the use later, the software that processes the file could then first get the datetime from the filename.

To put the same datetime at the end of each row, some simple code could be written:

- Make a string containing a separator and the datetime.
- Read the lines from the file, append the above string and write back to a new file.

This way a conversion from datetime to string is only done once, and converting the file should not take much longer than copying the file on disk.

Comment: This does not actually provide any sort of answer. OP's question shows that they are already aware of pretty much everything you wrote here. Just because the question is incomplete and poorly asked, does not give you an excuse to make a similar answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm sorry, but the OP's answer shows that it currently takes 2 hours, and at the same time asks for a faster way. The second part in my answer should only take 5-10 minutes instead (it also eliminates/prevents 680M date convertions in case those were used). The first part of the answer does it for free (depending on the need later on, putting the date in the filename could be enough).

Comment: How do you know that disk I/O isn't the bottleneck here (it probably is)

Comment: @MadPhysicist 5-10 minutes is actually the disk I/O (reading and writing 19GB). Appending that prepared string to each line shouldn't add much to the processing time (because it will be I/O bound anyway).